# Script writing in java for elasticsearch metric aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-java-api

I want to write following elasticsearch aggregation query in java. I am not able to write script for this in java , please help

```
"aggs":{
 "AVG_MEMORY_USAGE": {
      "avg": {
            "script": {"lang": "expression", "source": "doc['ProcessingTimeInMilliSecs']/doc['timezone']" }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this:

```
Script script = new 
Script("doc['ProcessingTimeInMilliSecs'].value/doc['timezone'].value");
AvgAggregationBuilder agg = 
AggregationBuilders.avg("AVG_MEMORY_USAGE").script(script);
Avg avg = agg.getAggregations().get("AVG_MEMORY_USAGE");
String avgValue = avg.getValue();
```

script uses painless language as a default so I did not explicitly mention the lang parameter in "script"